# What is the meaning of ctime and mtime on block device node

Tags: kernel, block-device

I have a mass storage device and sometimes its timestamps update:

```
$ stat /dev/sda
  File: ‘/dev/sda’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 21920486    Links: 1     Device type: 8,0
Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    6/    disk)
Access: 2017-01-30 14:46:01.843548633 +0200
Modify: 2017-01-30 14:46:01.843548633 +0200
Change: 2017-01-30 14:46:01.843548633 +0200
 Birth: -

$ stat /dev/sda
  File: ‘/dev/sda’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 21920486    Links: 1     Device type: 8,0
Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    6/    disk)
Access: 2017-01-30 14:47:33.412878263 +0200
Modify: 2017-01-30 14:47:33.412878263 +0200
Change: 2017-01-30 14:47:33.412878263 +0200
 Birth: -
```

What is the logic in the kernel and/or sd driver w.r.t. updating these? I just do not know where to look in the kernel source.